# Android Studio: Unable to Generate Signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

While trying to generate signed apk using Android Studio, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (com.tokom.globol.CustomGrid) [Instantiatable]
```

I tried to solve this issue by using super in my class but it shows error with red lines.

Here is **CustomGrid.java**

```
package com.tokom.globol;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] web;
    private final int[] Imageid;
    public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web = web;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);

        } else {
            grid = convertView;

        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        textView.setText(web[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);

        return grid;
    }

}
```

and This is how i call the class in mainActivity:

```
CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any help would be appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding the default constructor of BaseAdapter? `public CustomGrid() { }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Error:Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (com.tokom.globol.CustomGrid) [Instantiatable]
```

That's our clue! Just add a default constructor to the CustomGrid class.

```
    public CustomGrid() {
    }
```

Comment: Read the first comment to the question 3 minutes before you posted this answer ;)

Comment: as yo can see i already have it defined
public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {

so if i create empty constructor it will give error.